# How to access request headers inside a component with Nuxt2

Tags: nuxt.js, amazon-cloudfront, server-side-rendering

I have a Nuxt project with server side rendering enabled, deployed to Lambda and CloudFront.

In my nuxt.js file, I am able to intercept the CloudFront headers like this:

```
const countryCode = req.header('cloudfront-viewer-country')
```

What would be the best way to pass the value of these headers into one of my pages, or components so that I can check them there?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `req` is only available in a Node.js context. Hence, once your app is hydrated you will not be able to have access to that one. Using `if (process.server) {` is still the way to go here IMO, store it into a cookie and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing that. Basically what you want to achieve is to transfer a server side only value to the client side.

Nuxt does this by injecting server side data needed by the client side through the global variable `window.__NUXT__`. It includes data from a lot of sources like:

1. `asyncData` page hook
2. `fetch` components hook
3. Vuex stores state
4. Runtime configs (env variables)

And probably others...

So, if you need this request header in a **single page component**: use `asyncData`.

```js
// pages/index.vue
export default {
  asyncData(ctx) {
    return {
      country: ctx.req.headers['cloudfront-viewer-country']
    }
  }
}
```

If you need it in a **single component**: use `fetch` hook:

```js
// pages/index.vue
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      country: 'default country value'
    }
  },
  fetch() {
    if (process.server) {
      this.country = this.$nuxt.context.req.headers['cloudfront-viewer-country']
    }
  }
}
```

If you need it **globally in the app**: use a vuex store with a server side plugin:

```js
// plugins/read-headers.server.js

export default const readHeaders = (ctx) => {
  const country = ctx.req.headers['cloudfront-viewer-country']
  this.$store.commit('SET_COUNTRY', country)
}
```

```js
// store/index.js

export const state = () => ({
  country: ''
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_COUNTRY(state, country) {
    state.country = country
  }
}
```